# How to serve legacy jsp pages alongside Spring MVC in spring boot?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a legacy project with some simple JSP pages in it.

We are slowly replacing those JSP pages with Spring MVC, but I need to keep serving those JSPs not yet implemented with the MVC pattern, as one single web app.

So, I should end up with something like this:

Situation A: 
/legacy-url1/index.jsp -> should still be available for access like a JSP page, no controllers.

Situation B:
/legacy-url2/index.jsp -> /new-url2/ -> should be served from a spring mvc controller, populating a view using thymeleaf html files.

Situation B is working, as expected, and I tried fiddling with SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and UrlFilenameViewController, like this:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();

        Properties urlProperties = new Properties();
        urlProperties.put("*.jsp", "urlFilenameViewController");

        mapping.setMappings(urlProperties);

        return mapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlFilenameViewController urlFilenameViewController() {
        UrlFilenameViewController urlFilenameViewController = new UrlFilenameViewController();
        urlFilenameViewController.setPrefix("/jsp/");

        return urlFilenameViewController;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I may be missing something, but my googling for an answer has been unsuccessful.

I am using spring boot with java configuration.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by [define view controllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller) for each old JSP page and by [configure 2 view resolvers](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial) with appropriate ordering.